# jquery paralax issue in chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-chrome

I'm using this script http://stephband.info/jparallax/demos/thumbnails.html on a website I'm developing - and am getting a weird bug in Chrome.

Sometimes when I hover over the content slider script  (http://bit.ly/IC5FIg), the left side of the sliding content sticks to the mouse, rather than it moving slowly from left to right as it is meant to.

[image: Example image]

If you refresh the page afterwards, it will usually work correctly.

Comment: Please post the code in question.

Comment: It doesn't make sense that you would only be encountering the problem in Chrome. Since it is webkit based you should be encountering it in Safari as well.